# blender 2.8 : temporarily show all visible objects in the scene

Tags: rendering, render-layers, collections, viewlayers

When dealing with collection, the object in the 3d viewport will be visible depends on current selected view layer. Some objects won't be visible as they have been excluded from current view layer. But when edit the 3d scene, i want to be able to see all visible objects temporarily so i can select them in viewport. So far i ussually add new temporary 'view layer' (which include all objects) and later delete it before doing the render. Is there any better way to do this ?

Thanks